# Ndb ndb.GeoPtProperty how to print in tempalte in python3 django

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, ndb

Value has been store in geo = ndb.GeoPtProperty
and i want to print this on django template
but obj print not value

even i have try to print attr

```
geo.lat # try this also
geo.latitude # try this also
```

this is also not working even full name

Comment: Can you provide a sample code or documentation that you follow? Can you also check this [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1065) and [`ndb` library for Google Cloud Datastore](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/) if this would solve your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `obj print not value`.

The following code works

```
class Geo(ndb.Model):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    location = ndb.GeoPtProperty()

    @classmethod
    def create_record(cls, latitude, longitude):
        return cls(location = ndb.GeoPt(latitude, longitude)).put()


    @classmethod
    def get_records(cls):
        return cls.query().fetch()


@app.route("/test_geo/")
def create_geo():
    key = Geo.create_record(52.37, 4.88)
    logger.info(f"key: {key}")

    output = Geo.get_records()
    for a in output:
        logger.info (f"lat:{a.location.lat}, long: {a.location.lon}")
        # The above line gives
        lat:52.37, long: 4.88

    return "done"
```